# Why declare global variables in file doesn't include? (c++)

Tags: c++

An unexpected result occurred when testing both Windows-VS-environment and Linux-Cmake-environment.

A global variable was declared, even though it is not in included file.

Here is Example codes.

---

CmakeLists.txt

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE( app.out main.cpp test.cpp )
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

test.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    Test();
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

static Test g_test;

Test::Test() {
    std::cout << "Construct Test\n";
}
```

---

What I expected **just return 0 at main**

actual result **print Construct Test**

Why this happening?

Comment: Static objects, at file scope, are generally initialised before `main()` is called.   If you don't include `test.cpp` in the project, it will not be linked in, so the object won't be instantiated, so won't be initialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer here is, simply, because this is how C++ works.

```
static Test g_test;
```

This instantiates an object of type `Test` in the `test.cpp` translation unit. Whether or not it is declared in some header file is immaterial. It is instantiated. So it exists. You are alive because you, yourself exist and not because your name is recorded in some birth certificate, somewhere.

All objects that get instantiated get constructed. Full stop. No exceptions. This is how C++ works on its basic fundamental level (they also get destroyed at some point, by the way, in the ordinary ebb and flow of program execution).

So, when you link your program with the compiled `test.cpp` module, your final application has whatever's in `test.cpp`. Which includes that object that gets instantiated in global scope.

Whether the object's declared in some header file that gets compiled is completely irrelevant. As long as the object exists, it gets constructed. Whether or not an object gets constructed does not depend on it being declared in the header file. It gets constructed by the virtue of its existence. All that a declaration in some header file does is exactly that: a declaration. An assertion that something exists. Somewhere. The compiler doesn't care. If the declaration is for an object the compiler now knows that it exists, somewhere, and it trusts that one of the `cpp`s that get compiled will instantiate this object. If not, you get a link failure, at some point.

All compliant C++ implementations work this way, whether it's Linux, Windows, or anything else. This is a fundamental part of C++.